# How to do a full outer join?

Tags: google-sheets, join, outer-join

I am trying to do the full join for the data below in two different sheets.

**Sheet 9:**

| Product ID | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | addi | 55 |
| 2 | fadi | 66 |
| 3 | sadi | 33 |

**Sheet10**

| Product ID | Variants | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 2000 |
| 2 | differ | 2001 |
| 3 | saddd | 336 |
| 4 | fsdfe | 2005 |

**Desired output sheet :**

| Product ID | Name | Quantity | Variants | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | addi | 55 | xyz | 2000 |
| 2 | fadi | 66 | differ | 2001 |
| 3 | sadi | 33 | saddd | 336 |
| 4 |  |  | fsdfe | 2005 |

Please also share if we have more columns to join like in sheet 1 and sheet 2 has two more columns like Year, product label etc then what should I change in your proposed solution

I am using this formula but its not returning the desired result

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Sheet9!A1:D; Sheet10!A1:D})), "where Col1 is not null"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Sheet9!A1:D; Sheet10!A1:D})), "where Col1 is not null")),,999^99)), TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet9!A1:D),,999^99)), Sheet9!C1:C}, 2, 0),""),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Sheet9!A1:D; Sheet10!A1:D})), "where Col1 is not null")),,999^99)), {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet10!A1:D),,999^99)), Sheet10!C1:C}, 2, 0),"")}})
```

Comment: And please include in your post the specific research you've already done and the formulas you yourself have already tried toward reaching your goal, keeping in mind that the volunteer-run free forums are designed to offer a little knowledge or "a nudge in the right" direction to people who have already done most of the work themselves (that is, the forums are not a place where anyone can come to get customized, time-intensive work done by experts at no cost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDITED to consider dynamic row matching.*

[See this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KmcWuF-e99oZL9kQFi2h77TG0gEnzHtxzCHJi_lBFNA/edit#gid=1101723319) to illustration, but overall there's a question of your setup, but I would break your problem into two steps.

**Get distinct list of ID's**

You can get that with this formula:

```
=unique(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,
    iferror(INdex(Sheet2!$A$2:$Z,0,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),""),
    iferror(INdex(Sheet1!$A$2:$Z,0,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!1:1,0)),"")),",")))
```

**Rest of Headers**

Then for each header, will they each always only be in 1 exclusively or 2 (not both)? Assuming so, this should work for each additional column. If two values ever exist in the two sheets, will join them in the same column.

```
=filter( 
 iferror(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A,Sheet1!$A:$Z,match(E$1,Sheet1!1:1,0),false),"")
 &iferror(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A,Sheet2!$A:$Z,match(E$1,Sheet2!1:1,0),false),"")
   ,$A$2:$A<>"")
```

There's probably a way to use the join function to do this more elegantly (if someone posts an answer showing me I'll upvote).

Comment: Fawad, I took a look at your formula. It really doesn't have "a small mistake." I took out just the first part by itself, and it was producing results that could not have been used in any part of a working solution. And with the very first section wrong, it could only have gone downhill as you tried to add more to it. Again, we're not trying to be unkind, just realistic. You are asking people to do free high-level work for you. Would you go to a bakery offering free one-inch pastry samples and expect them to cater a party for you for free (even if you tried to make the desserts and failed)?

Comment: (cont.) Even *if* your formula only had "a small mistake" (which it doesn't), it would still require an expert and a considerable time investment to analyze the formula piece by piece, test the components and find such an error—often even longer than just writing a new formula from scratch. And either in your case would constitute real work for which we would be charging any other client. Think of forums as the bakery offering one-inch samples, not as a place that caters parties for free (even for people who tried really hard to make their own desserts but failed).

Comment: thanks @ErikTyler. I feel like I've become more impatient on such things lately. Good luck Fawad, thanks for accepting.